# I can't create a new project

Tags: android

I just upgraded Android Studio3.3.2, But I can't create a new project.Here is the error log.The development language I use is java

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find a
>   JavaToKotlinConversionProvider, even though one should be bundled with
>   Studio    at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.JavaToKotlinHandler.getJavaToKotlinConversionProvider(JavaToKotlinHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.TemplateValueInjector.addKotlinVersion(TemplateValueInjector.java:410)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.template.TemplateValueInjector.setProjectDefaults(TemplateValueInjector.java:282)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModuleModel.handleFinished(NewProjectModuleModel.java:150)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.handleFinished(ModelWizard.java:403)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.goForward(ModelWizard.java:331)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizardDialog$FinishAction.doAction(ModelWizardDialog.java:311)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1840)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>     at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
>     at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
>     at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)  at
>   java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1077)    at
>   com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:698)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:430)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1690)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1639)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:84)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:255)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:272)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:304)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:307)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:106)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:294)
>     at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:114)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:111)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:114)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:529)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:49)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:549)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6548)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)    at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6313)  at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)  at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4903)     at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)     at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
>     at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)    at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4725)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)   at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:817)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:754)
>     at
>   com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:394)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Plugins -> Kotlin and update the Kotlin plugin to the last version even though you don't write your code in Kotlin. It happened to me too,it doesnt matter that you write in java.

After it just try to restart and invalidate caches!

[image: Here is how to do it]

Good Luck!